# count string occurances in MutableMap in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a mutable map consisting elements added in a while loop. Is ends when `x` is given from the input. My task from hyperskill is to print that element which occurs the most, however if there is equal number of occurances it gives me the element which appeared faster.
So given:

`a,a,a,b,b -> a`  
`c,a,c,a  -> c` 
`a,b,c,a  -> a`

```
val words = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()
    var x_is_used = false
    var index = 0
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    while (!x_is_used) {
        var input = scan.next()
        if (input== "x") {
            x_is_used = true
        } else {

            words[index] = input
            index++

        }}
```

How can I accomplish it? I tried not to make this post a duplicate. It is a task from introduction section to maps,lists and sets. Although I'm not a newbie to Kotlin its documentation gets me confused.

Looking at map docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/

What caught my eye are functions `.count` and `.filter`
But I am not sure how to use them.

Task pic:

[image]

Comment: Well firstly, you can never guarantee order in a map, so I think you might have the wrong data structure?

Comment: I updated task picture, so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing too much information, I think.  Consider what your map will look like after entering (say) a, b, c, a:

```
3 -> c
1 -> a
4 -> a
2 -> b
```

(Maps are not usually ordered, so those pairs could be in any order.)

If you wanted to store each input in sequence, then a List would be more appropriate.

However, this problem doesn't *care* about the order in which the values were entered — all it cares about is how many there were of each.  And to store that, you could use a map from input value to the number of times it occurs.  Once you have that structure, the rest should be straightforward.

(If you're learning the language, you'll learn most by trying to implement it yourself, so I strongly suggest you don't read the rest of this answer until after you have something working yourself!  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to mark code as a spoiler without losing all the formatting, nor to mark multiple paragraphs.  So instead, I'll do it the old-fashioned way and leave a gap…)

⠀
⠀

⠀

↓

⠀

⠀

⠀

↓

⠀

⠀

⠀

↓

⠀

⠀

⠀

↓
⠀

⠀

⠀

Here's one possible solution:

```
val wordCounts = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
while (true) {
    val input = scan.next()
    if (input == "x")
        break
    wordCounts.merge(input, 1, Int::plus)
}

println(wordCounts.maxByOrNull{ it.value }?.key)
```

As you can see, this is rather simpler!

Rather than maintain a flag variable, it's simpler just to `break` out of the loop when you reach the end.  (In the real world, instead of using a special value like "x" to mark the end, it might be neater to read until the end of the input: if reading a file, that would be end of the file; if direct user input, the user would press the end-of-file combination (e.g. Ctrl+D on macOS/Unix) to end.  And the code would simply check for `null`.)

Updating the map would be as simple as:

```
wordCounts[input] = wordCounts[input] + 1
```

…*if* we knew the input was already present.  To handle that too, you could do:

```
wordCounts[input] = (wordCounts[input] ?: 0) + 1
```

…but the [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) call is slightly simpler once you know what it's doing.

And to get the most common word, you just search the map for entry with the highest value (i.e. the largest count).  You could do that manually, but there's a nice [`maxByOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html) function for doing exactly that.  (Note that it can return null if the input is empty, so we have to handle that.)

And once you have that entry, you can print its key, which is the most common word!

Comment: How does it prints the first value given? Suppose I'll give it a b c d, why does it print a?

Comment: The documentation for `maxByOrNull()` says “Returns the first element yielding the largest value of the given function”.  Most maps don't have an order, but `mutableMapOf()` says “The returned map preserves the entry iteration order.” — so if there are many input values with the same count, this will print the one that occurs first in the input.